# Provider ValueNotifier listen not working on some Pages on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

`listen` is not working. when hot reload value is updated.

**Page A**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    ValueNotifier<List<ProductModel>> selectNotifier = Provider.of<ValueNotifier<List<ProductModel>>>(context, listen: true);
```

**Widget**

```
 Text('${selectNotifier.value.length}'),
```

**Page B**

```
 InkWell(
     onTap: () {
         selectNotifier.value.add(selectProduct);                        
     },
```

**main.dart**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ValueNotifier<List<ProductModel>>>(
          create: (_) => ValueNotifier<List<ProductModel>>([]),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: CustomTheme.themeData,
        onGenerateRoute: Router.generateRoute,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Version**

```
provider: ^4.1.2
```

**Flutter Version**

```
1.17.2
```

I tried below ways to fix this issue. But I don't know what is right way(best way).

**1st way**

After downgrade Flutter and Provider, now is working. why is that?

```
provider: 3.2.0
git checkout v1.12.13-hotfixes
```

**2nd way**

Or it is working this way too.//but warning on the IDE

```
onTap: () {
             selectNotifier.value.add(selectProduct); 
             selectNotifier.notifyListeners(); //info: The member 'notifyListeners' can only be used within instance members of subclasses of 'package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart'.                      
         },
```

But warning disappear, after adding this `ChangeNotifier`,

```
class _viewState extends State<View> with ChangeNotifier{
```

and also getting error after adding `ChangeNotifier`

> The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
>   _CartItemViewState.dispose failed to call super.dispose.
>
> dispose() implementations must always call their superclass dispose()
>   method, to ensure that all the resources used by the widget are fully
>   released.

**3rd way**

I don't get any issue on this way, but I used so many ValueNotifier in my production app, so, others are not a List. I don't know how to change other types.

```
 onTap: () {
        selectNotifier.value = List.from(selectNotifier.value)..add(widget.productModel);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this question, **3rd way** is the correct way.

```
onTap: () {
        selectNotifier.value = List.from(selectNotifier.value)..add(widget.productModel);
}
```

Comment: This is pretty nifty.

Comment: However, this hits hard: there's the cost of copying the list with `List.from`. Alternatively using a `ValueNotifier` subclass, with methods for mutating the list, and `notifyListeners()` in said method, would be a performance enhancements in some scenarios (list is too big and/or list is updated too frequently)

Comment: See entire discussion here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29958